# UITableview cells don't show up until you scroll. also with in main queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tried:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{  
    [self.tableView reloadData];  
});
```

but it doesn't help. Could anyone fix this?

Sooo, in first pic we can see 1,2,3,4,6 lines, but when I scrool down, when they can't see, go to another page, coming back, and scrolling up, they aren't there.(pic 2) [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npzq6.jpg)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzOU3.jpg)

Comment: You need to provide a lot more relevant details. No one can help with what little info you have provided.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Usually if you have a table view it should load without any scrolling. Although I remember encountering this once but forgot where

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by UI updates on a background thread.  In each method or block that updates the UI assert that it's on the main thread:

```
NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"UI updates should be on the main thread");
```

to catch it.